For which languages can branching be determined by static analysis?
Python has methods like getattr() which can be used to branch arbitrarily at runtime. As a result, static code analysis tools can't be certain what functions a program will call. A good example comes from Vulture, which is a library that tries to find dead code:
import os

class Greeter:
    def greet(self):
        print("Hi")

def hello_world():
    message = "Hello, world!"
    greeter = Greeter()
    func_name = "greet"
    greet_func = getattr(greeter, func_name)
    greet_func()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello_world()

In the above example, func_name must be evaluated to know where the program would branch.
Are there programming languages that intentionally or unintentionally ensure static analysis tools will always be able to tell where a function will branch? If so, what are some examples?
Secondarily, is there name for this property?
Edit: Per D.W.'s answer, possible branches would include unreachable code and code behind if False:, etc.

Can you clarify your edit? What do you mean by "possible branches"? Did you mean to accept D.W.'s answer, or is there something missing from it?

Please don't use "Edit:".  Instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  We want to build up a repository of knowledge that will be useful for others in the future.  You don't find "Edit:" in Wikipedia or in an encyclopedia.

if f() then g() requires that f terminates for g to be called.

I think the term you're looking for is early binding

Most languages have features that make it undecidable to tell where a function will branch or what function will be invoked by a particular function call.  Features that can make this difficult include reflection, function pointers, higher-order functions, self-modifying code, lack of memory safety, and use of eval.
Indeed, even conditional branches can make it hard.  Consider this code snippet:
def dispatcher(n):
    if n==0:
        f()
    elsif n==1:
        g()
    ...

It is undecidable whether f is called, because that requires predicting all possible values of n, which is undecidable.

Thanks for the reply. I hadn't considered all of those different ways to introduce runtime branching. I think static analysis should include both f() and g() as possibilities. I have made an edit to my question.
